# Css convertion see the screenshot below

Tags: css

Im a css newbie, can someone help me how to achieve this in css, I have a screenshot below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aZlM.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

```css
*{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
div{
    padding:20px;
    background:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
h1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr max-content 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  background:white;

}

h1 span{
      background:black;
      color:white;
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 5px 10px ;
}


h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  border-top: 2px solid currentColor;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h1>
    <span>LATEST WORK</span>
</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should provide example code of what you've already tried in your question to avoid being downvoted.

However, you can achieve what you shared in the screenshot with the following:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkslategray;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span class="text">LATEST WORK</span>
</div>
```

The line is positioned behind the text with `z-index`. Note the `transform` needed to properly center the line vertically with the text. You could also achieve something similar with less DOM elements using [before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo elements.